# Why is the Guava library included with Vaadin 14 not appearing on my project's classpath?

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, classpath, vaadin-flow

Vaadin 14.1.0alpha4 automatically includes the [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) version 25 library via its Maven configuration. See the screenshot below, listed on the left side.

Yet in my own code, when referring to a class in Google Guava, IntelliJ marks it as a compiler error. IntelliJ offers to “Add library Guava to classpath”. In the screenshot below, see the two orange arrows on the right side.

➥ Why is the Guava listed as a downloaded library listed in my Vaadin 14 project not already on the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))? Why is Guava not available to my code?

[image]

Comment: Could you add the (relevant part of the) POM to your question?

Comment: @JFMeier No, unfortunately I cannot show the relevant part of the POM. My own POM calls on other mysterious configuration (more POM files?) provided by Vaadin. So I have never seen that part. I am no Maven maven.

Comment: Generally, it is advisable to add all dependencies that you use in your source code, _directly_ to your POM and not rely on transitive resolution. You must be careful, though, in picking the "right" version as the classpath can only have one version of a dependency and you might destroy other parts if you add an incompatible version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [empty project default](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) seems to only include that dependency in a test scope:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep "guava"

[INFO]    |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:25.0-jre:test
```

The maven panel is more precise on what dependencies are available in what scope and what module:

[image: maven panel dependencies]

Comment: Can I simply add a dependency for Guava in my own POM without disturbing or conflicting with Vaadin? Can my dependency use a newer version of Guava?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, since you are not distributing the test-bench (or the tests in general) with your app. But there is the odd chance, that your functional tests might be disturbed by that.

Comment: That is always a bit of a try and error thing. Yes you can simply add that dependency into you own pom. maven will resolve using a "shortest path" method. So transitive dependencies are replaced. If the other things you have work with a newer version depends on the backward compatibility of guava. I would think no bigger jumps are possible. Since it is test scope by default and you may not use those testing features you could jump version. You need to manage dependencies yourself. Also with maven. So when choosing: better safe than sorry :)